# socat struggle to create serial ports

Tags: port, socat

For testing purposes I want to use **socat** to create virtual serial ports to use in my Python program.

I have limited success, but struggle again and again with the many options in socat. I use this command in Ubuntu Linux:

```
sudo socat -d -d  pty,b9600,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyS90    pty,b9600,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyS91
```

As it should, it creates the virtual ports like /dev/pts/2 and 4, and links them to /dev/ttyS90 and *91. It does not work without sudo (it fails with unable to unlink for the *90, *91 ports, although the regular user is in the dialout group).

[image]

But as you see the permissions 'lrwxrwxrwx' look like reading/writing for everybody. However, this is NOT true: I CANNOT use these devices unless I am root. The file manager (=Nemo) gives this result:

[image]

The permissions are significantly different. Huh?

After issuing 'sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyS90' (and same for *91) nothing changes in the terminal output, because it is already, but incorrectly, showing 777 permissions, but the Nemo output changes to

[image]

And now I can use the ports as regular user! How comes? Am I doing something wrong?

And one more socat problem: the above socat command gives an 8-bit, no-parity connection, but I really need a 7-bit, even-parity connection. My attempts to implement this by juggling some of the many options all failed. I am lost; any insight?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the permission on `/dev/pts/2` and `/dev/pts/4` instead of on the link

Comment: unfortunately this is not helping. Before I issue the socat command, the pts/2 and 4 don't exist. So obviously, I can't change anything on them. And I cannot create them, without using sudo. Once so created, the ttyS9X are listed as shown above. the 2 and 4 have user root and group tty (and I am in tty).
But I am wondering whether the bigger issue might be the incorrect listing made by the "ls" command? This is so basic - should that not come out correct?

Comment: Correct that the pts don't exist before `socat`, I changed the permissions afterwards. when created I think they look something like this: `crw--w---- 1 root tty  136, 0 Nov  6 15:12 /dev/pts/0` My user is part of the tty group so I ran `sudo chmod g+r /dev/pts/?` to add read to the group. That is when I was able to read from them without sudo. Oh I don't think there is an error with ls because those are the permissions of the soft-link, not the pts.

Comment: The ls command gives lrwxrwxrwx for the /dev/ttyS90, and crw—w---- for the /dev/pts/, to which the S90 is linked. My filemanager (Nemo) gives xrw—w---- for both. The latter makes sense, because the ls command pretends to see all permissions for everyone, which is false!
The suggestion for changing permsiions on the pts may come in handy, thanks.